# All Id into a single column

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

select ProductId from Products
I am getting the output as follows:
ProductId

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

I want to get output as like follow:

ProductID

```
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Use `string_agg()` in Postgres

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-aggregation+sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
declare @aa varchar (200)
set @aa = ''

select @aa = 
case when @aa = ''
then cast(Productid as varchar)
else @aa + coalesce(',' + cast(Productid as varchar), '')
end
from Products

print @aa
```